# Select the first cell of each row placed after a merged cell using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with class `evo-table`, which has two cells of row span of 4, followed by four rows with two cells each [(Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrygW.png). I want to select the first cell of each of these rows using JavaScript. I know I could simply add classes to cells and style it using CSS but I'm restricted to the Table structure below. I am able to select and add CSS to the first cell of the first row using `$(".highlight").next().css("background","lightgreen");` but I'm not able to select the first cell of the rest of the rows. Here's the code:

**HTML:** (This is a DEMO only)

```
<table class="evo-table">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4">Merged Cell 1</td>
        <td rowspan="4" class="highlight">Merged Cell 2</td>
        <td>Unmerged Cell 1</td>
        <td>Unmerged Cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Unmerged Cell 3</td>
        <td>Unmerged Cell 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Unmerged Cell 5</td>
        <td>Unmerged Cell 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Unmerged Cell 7</td>
        <td>Unmerged Cell 8</td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

**jQuery/JavaScript:**

```
var tableObj = $(".evo-table");
var mergeLength = $(".evo-table .highlight").attr("rowspan");
var firstRowAfterHighlight = $(".evolution-table .highlight").parent().next().index + 1;
$(".highlight").next().css("background","lightgreen");
for (count = 0;  count < mergeLength; count = count + 1) {
    $(".evolution-table tr:nth-child(" + (firstRowAfterHighlight + count) + ") td:first-child:not(.highlight)").css("background-color", "green")
}
```

I am using the `rowspan` value of `.highlight` cell to find the number of rows (I could use `$(".evo-table tr").length;` to get it but the previous one is more useful in my case as I want to select rows which are immediately to the right of the cell) and I'm finding the index of the row after first row and using `count` variable of the `for` statement to move on to the next row, and using the `:first-child` selector on `td` to select the first cell of every row. The code doesn't seem to work.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/41bjrq7q/17/)

Please reply if you spot any errors in my code, need more details or have a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `.each` function to iterate over every row.  And then I used teh `:not` selector to ignore elements with the attribute `[rowspan]`.

```js
$(".evo-table tr").each(function () {
  $(this).find("td:not([rowspan]):first").css("background-color", "red")
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family:Arial;
}
.evo-table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border:1px solid lightgrey;
}
.evo-table td {
  padding:4px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
.highlight {
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="evo-table">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4">Merged Cell 1</td>
        <td rowspan="4" class="highlight">Merged Cell 2</td>
        <td>Unmerged Cell 1</td>
        <td>Unmerged Cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Unmerged Cell 3</td>
        <td>Unmerged Cell 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Unmerged Cell 5</td>
        <td>Unmerged Cell 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Unmerged Cell 7</td>
        <td>Unmerged Cell 8</td>
    </tr>
<table>
<div style="font-size:12px;color:lightgrey;">
Yellow = .highlight class; Green = Selected using jQuery;
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do this for styling, you don't need javascript, you can do it with plain CSS3:

```
td[rowspan] + td:not([rowspan]), tr > td:not([rowspan]):first-child {
    background: red;
}
```

It selects a `td` without a `rowspan` that directly follows after a `td` with the `rowspan` attribute (the first `tr`) and all first `td` in a `tr` that do not have a `rowspan` attribute (all other `tr`).

If you want it in JavaScript, you can use the same CSS selector with jQuery. No need to loop over the table rows:

```
$('td[rowspan] + td:not([rowspan]), tr > td:not([rowspan]):first-child')
```